# Very large uploads with PHP

Tags: php, upload, large-files

I want to allow uploads of very large files into our PHP application (hundred of megs - 8 gigs). There are a couple of problems with this however.

Browser:

- HTML uploads have crappy feedback, we need to either poll for progress (which is a bit silly) or show no feedback at all
- Flash uploader puts entire file into memory before starting the upload

Server:

- PHP forces us to set post_max_size, which could result in an easily exploitable DOS attack. I'd like to not set this setting globally.
- The server also requires some other variables to be there in the POST vars, such as an secret key. We'd like to be able to refuse the request right away, instead of after the entire file is uploaded.

Requirements:

- HTTP is a must.
- I'm flexible with client-side technology, as long as it works in a browser.
- PHP is not a requirement, if there's some other technology that will work well on a linux environment, that's perfectly cool.

Comment: If the PHP internals don't buffer the entire input, you could write a module that will check the ID in the header before the POST body against a database. Run the special server on another port, generate the ID from your main webserver.

Comment: Are you indicating that Flash is off the table because it reads the entire file into memory before starting the upload?  (Just clarifying)

Comment: I want to see what happens when a lot of your webusers upload 8GB files simultaneous.

Comment: @ElzoValugi: is that serious question? If so, perhaps you can rephrase it a little bit so I can help answer.

Comment: it was a statement, not a question. HTTP is not the best protocol for your problem. you should choose another tool for transferring these files from A to B, a solution that is not prone to disaster.

Comment: Alright, so it was intended as unhelpful sarcasm. Got it. Thankfully I already solved this problem in '09 successfully.

Comment: pluploader is brilliant for this. Because it chunks uploads in 1MB (by default) you can get around the php size limits.

Comment: Hi ..How did u solve this problem ?

Comment: @MarcoZen back then we used some custom PHP extensions. Doubt they are still around. If I had the same problem today, I would write a small microservice in Go or Node.js to specifically handle the upload.

Comment: Thanks @Evert. Would pluploader work for your scenario ?

Comment: @MarcoZen, like I said... it's been 11 years. Most recently we used Node.js and native HTML apis for multi-gigabyte video uploads. Works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks @Evert. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a Java applet? That's how we had to do it at a company I previously worked for. I know applets suck, especially in this day and age with all our options available, but they really are the most versatile solution to desktop-like problems encountered in web development. Just something to consider.

Comment: java applet might do the trick, but that's only really half the problem.

Comment: Wordpress uses a flash based uploader.

Answer (score 14):

upload_max_filesize can be set [on a per-directory basis](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.file-uploads); the same goes for post_max_size

e.g.:

```
<Directory /uploadpath/>
  php_value upload_max_filesize 10G
  php_value post_max_size 10G
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Does that mean you actually *need* 10G RAM on the server or is this just a setting for avoiding upload attacks/mistakes?

Comment: @MartinWickman apparently not according to a test I did. Unless you open the file, of course. I was able to upload a 500MB file, inc. `move_uploaded_file` while only using 0.2MB according to `memory_get_usage(TRUE)`

Comment: @artfulrobot `memory_get_usage` omits a lot -- for example, if you SELECT a gig of data from a database, you'll see your memory usage go up by about a gig in `top`, but `memory_get_usage` and PHP's memory limit won't count any of it until you fetch it from the database resource into local PHP variables.  I'd try watching apache's memory utilization in `top` during the upload to be sure.

Comment: @FrankFarmer I watched apache in top, uploaded a 1GB file, no increase.

Answer (score 7):

**Python Handler?**

Using a Python POST handler instead of PHP. Generate a unique identifier from your PHP app that the client can put in the HTTP headers. With mod_python to reject or accept the large upload before the entire POST body is transmitted.

I think
http://www.modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/dir-handlers-hph.html

Allows you to check headers and decline the rest of the POST input. I haven't tried it but might be the right path?

Looking at the source of mod_python, the buffering of the input via read() seems to allow bit-at-a-time evaluation of the HTTP input. Headers are first.

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/quetzalcoatl/mod_python/trunk/src/filterobject.c

Comment: This looks like the only real solution to the question posted so far.

Answer (score 7):

It's old I know, but maybe someone have this problem nowdays ,too. 
Now you can do this with only Javascript and, say, PHP. No Flash or Java required on client side.

demo: http://dnduploader.filkor.org/

The idea is to slice the files with Javascript's Blob slice() method...

Answer (score 2):

You can set the post_max_size for just scripts in 1 directory.  Place your upload script there, and allow only that script to handle large sizes.  It's still possible for that script to be attacked with large/useless files, but it avoids setting it globally.

Use that with APC and you might be able to work out something good:
[IBM Developer works article on APC](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-v525/index.html)

Comment: APC is difficult to use in our load balanced setup. We don't use cookie fixation, so in order to properly use this we'd need to poll the actual server the file is uploaded to (which kinda sucks in our situation).

Just having the post_max_size on 1 directory also does not do the trick for me, because it's still susceptible for DOS attacks on that 1 directory, and I want to block requests if they contain invalid GET data right when it starts..

Answer (score 2):

Tried all of this... this is by far the best I have used yet...

http://www.uploadify.com/

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [jumploader.com](http://www.jumploader.com)

A good java-applet for uploading.

I've used it for uploading images and it works fine. Haven't tried with bigger files than 10MB, but i should work for really big files too.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into using APC to check the progress and total file size. Here is a [good blog post](http://www.haughin.com/2007/10/23/php-upload-progress-with-php-52-apc/) about it. It might help.

Comment: The APC trick requires polling, which I don't like because of our load balanced scenario.

Comment: You can't poll because each poll request might be set to a different server than the download started on?

Comment: You could store the poll key in a database

Comment: Peter D - correct
Aiden, this is not possible because I can only request information on the upload (even with the key) on the server where the upload started.

Comment: Ah I see. What if you had an internal script launched to poll the right server and store those results in a central place and have a handler on the front-end?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use Webdav and Javascript in the browser

**AJAX Big file upload, with progress, to WebDAV**

http://www.webdavsystem.com/ajax/programming/upload_progress

**A simple library**

http://debris.demon.nl/projects/davclient.js/doc/README.html

You can then get the JS to redirect the user to a success page. Secret keys and what-not can be handled in a PHP prelude before handing off the JS Client->WebDAV

Comment: Javascript will not allow me to read the contents of a local file.

I don't know exactly how 'webdavsystem' does it, but I think they simply still use a standard upload and have a special handler for that on the server.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into [FTP, SSH or SCP](http://us.php.net/ssh2) this allows you to upload a large file and still have access control over the file as well. This might take a little longer to implement but its probably the most secure way I could think of.

Comment: We don't want to really go this route.. HTTP is simple so we don't want to overcomplicate the environment. We are open to using something else than PHP on the server-side, but HTTP is a must.

Answer (score 0):

I know it sucks to add another dependency but in my experience, most websites that are doing something like this are using flash on the client side, and uploading the large file as chunks

adobe as a [howto on flash file uploads](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00001054.html)

I also found this tutorial on codeproject:

[Multiple File Upload With Progress Bar Using Flash and ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/FlashUpload.aspx)

PS - I know you're using PHP and not .net, I figured the important part was the flash ;)

Comment: Unfortunately flash has been problematic. Flash puts the entire file into memory before uploading, resulting in a complete freeze of my mac for a couple of minutes :(

Comment: The FileReference class in Flash does not allow direct file access, only upload.

Comment: Damn these security layers ;P

Answer (score 0):

I've had success with [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/), and I would recommend it.  It's a jQuery/Flash script that handles large uploads, and you can pass extra parameters to it (like the secret key).  To solve the server-side issues, simply use the following code.  The changes take affect just for the script they're called in:

```
//Check to see if the key is there
if(!isset($_POST['secret_key']) || !isValid($_POST['secret_key']))
{
    exit("Invalid request");
}
function isValid($key)
{
    //Put your validation code here.
}

//This line changes the timeout.
//Give it a value in seconds (3600 = 1 hour)
set_time_limit(3600);

//Set these amounts to whatever you need.
ini_set("post_max_size","8192M");
ini_set("upload_max_filesize","8192M");

//Generally speaking, the memory_limit should be higher
//than your post size.  So make sure that's right too.
ini_set("memory_limit","8200M");
```

**EDIT** In response to your comment:

Given what you've said, I'm afraid you may not be able to meet your requirements over http.  All of the solutions out there are code that add features to http that it was never designed for.

Like you said yourself, it's a simple protocol.  Apart from writing your own client software that runs outside of the browser, a java applet, or using a different protocol (like FTP, which was designed for this), you might not get what you want.

I've done the best I could within the given constraints.  Sorry I couldn't do better.

Comment: Flash does not work well, read the above comments.

Setting the upload_max_filesize and post_max_size after the script has already started will have no effect.

Answer (score -2):

Try this: http://www.simple2ftp.com uses a Java based FTP applet from within a clever PHP application wrapper.

Comment: "HTTP is a must"... But isn't this based on FTP?