# Php file uploading warning message

Tags: php, file-upload, php-ini

I need to upload a video file. Here's my code

```php
 if(($_FILES["file"]["type"]=="application/octet-stream") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"]=="video/x-ms-wmv"))
          {
        if($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
          {
          echo "Error: ".$_FILES["file"]["error"]."<br />";

          }
        else if(file_exists("videos/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
              {
              echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
              }
            else
              {
              move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"videos/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);

        $filename=$_FILES["file"]["name"];  
        $type=$_FILES["file"]["type"];
        $size=($_FILES["file"]["size"]/1024);
        $path="".$_FILES["file"]["name"];
       if(($ins=mysql_query("insert into achieva_video values('','".$_REQUEST['vname']."','".$_REQUEST['courid']."','".$filename."','".$path."','".$size."','".$type."','Active')"))==true)
        {
            header("location:viewcoursevideo.php?ins=1");
        }  
        else
        {
            echo("<script>alert('Failure Please try again later');</script>");
        }
     }
          }

    else
     {
      echo "<script>alert('Invalid File Type');</script>)";

     }
```

I'm bit confused with this warning message when I try to upload a video file.

```
"PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of 9311816 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0"
```

> I've set the following preferences in the php ini:

```
 memory limit = 150M
  upload file size = 120M 
  post max size = 120M
```

The file has not been updated. it takes long time and just shows this warning.

Comment: Google ftw: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6315358/251311

Comment: did you check phpinfo() to see if those values are being applied?

Comment: Yes. I checked. Everything is set

Comment: Have you tried setting the values as bytes instead of using M notation

Comment: you mean to say something like 9311815b?

Answer (score 0):

the message seems clear: you have an upload limit set to 8M (8388608 bytes) and you are uploading a file of 9M (9311816 bytes). Are you really sure these settings in php.ini are working?

```
 memory limit = 150M
 upload file size = 120M 
 post max size = 120M
```

Comment: But i could see in the phpinfo the preferences set as above. How to check working or not?

Comment: Could it be that the problem is that you reach the max execution time for the php script? For examplet the uplaod is slow and it takes too much time. try to increase the value of max_execution_time !

Comment: The max_execution_time is set to 3600s means 1hr.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be like this? (underscores, max!)

```
memory_limit = 150M
upload_max_filesize = 120M
post_max_size = 120M
```

Comment: Yes I set it in this way only

Comment: Are you on a shared webserver?

Comment: Yes. What is the problem with it?

Comment: Well on a shared webserver, you may have a "master value" that you can't change.