# Post Values in my PHP Site return null

Tags: php, ubuntu, memory-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Warning: POST Content-Length of 113 bytes exceeds the limit of -1988100096 bytes in Unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315358/php-warning-post-content-length-of-113-bytes-exceeds-the-limit-of-1988100096-b)

I am submitting a form to a php file but in post there is nothing come from form and check in apache error_log and get below error:

```
PHP Warning:  Unknown: POST Content-Length of 273 bytes exceeds the limit of -201326592 bytes in Unknown on line 0,
```

Please suggest me how to fix this error.

in my `php.ini` settings

```
upload_max_filesize 2000M
post_max_size 800M
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315358/php-warning-post-content-length-of-113-bytes-exceeds-the-limit-of-1988100096-b

Comment: Thanks i have fix it with this link help.

Answer (score 1):

If you [follow the advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315358/php-warning-post-content-length-of-113-bytes-exceeds-the-limit-of-1988100096-b), you'll find that the suggestion is 2000M exceeds the signed integer limit of your machine, so the integer value gets truncated and becomes negative. To achieve the maximum upload size, set

`upload_max_filesize = 2147483647`

and don't use 2000M for any other integer properties in your php.ini