# Strange PHP error, where does it come from? Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Today i was making a file upload for avatars, everything works great, it resizes the images etc, but occasionally when selecting a large and invalid file it produces this error :

```
Warning: POST Content-Length of 52091839 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0
You did not select a file to upload.
```

This does not happen all the time, just occasionally. Normally it just gives the correct error message when a file is too big.

Does anyone have an idea where this error comes from, and why it shows?

Thanks!

Comment: If the answer doesn't work you may want to look at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315358/php-warning-post-content-length-of-113-bytes-exceeds-the-limit-of-1988100096-b

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you need to increase [`post_max_size`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) in php.ini.  If you have not already also increased [`upload_max_filesize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize), you are likely to need to increase it as well.

```
# php.ini
# Allow huge files:
# Post usually needs to be bigger than file upload size!
post_max_size = 256M
upload_max_filesize 128M
```

Comment: Thats not the problem i think, because if i have a file that is too big to post it shows the correct error : The uploaded file exceeds the maximum allowed size in your PHP configuration file. this is a different error which i havent setup anywhere

Comment: @user1362916 The two directives will cause different errors. Make sure both are large enough.

Answer (score 2):

Update your `post_max_size` in php.ini to a larger value

`upload_max_filesize` sets the max file size that a user can upload while `post_max_size` sets the maximum amount of data that can be sent via a POST in a form. That might be the reason why you get big file error sometimes when you try upload a single file of large size but when you try to upload multiple files the above error is raised.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the way the file is coded when uploaded.

Basically it is "seen" as a very large POST.

So you want your `php.ini` `post_max_size` larger than your `upload_max_filesize` value.

Depending on the encoding you use, it should be from 60% to 100% larger.

Otherwise you might have a max file size of 5 M, but this gets encoded to 8.01 M; when that happens, the check for file size passes, but the one for post body size fails. Hence your error.