# File upload issue in Yii/PHP

Tags: php

I have a situation here, while uploading larger files(greater than `10mb`) nothing happens, no file is uploading, no db entry, no error messages etc., I'am using Yii.. `phpinfo` says `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` are `1G` and `max_execution_time` is `3600` .After submitting the form, the page loads for sometime and came back to its old stage(fresh form). can't find the exact issue.

**Update:**

After checking server error log I got this

`PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of 17481302 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0`, then what to do?

**update 2**

The issue resolved

> When you see error like that in log, you can check these values
>
> upload_max_filesize = post_max_size =
>
> in /etc/php.ini (not in user’s php.ini)

Comment: just store the reference of that file in your db not the whole file.

Comment: @RishabhRaj The form contains some other inputs too, thts wht i said..

Comment: did you try increasing the max_allowed_packet in the my.cnf file?

Comment: @RishabhRaj, Ihave my php.ini config file, where is this my.cnf file located

Comment: i posted an answer.have a look.

Comment: use command line for the changes u want to do,that will be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server Admin's Reply Regarding the issue,

When you see error like that in log, you can check these values

```
upload_max_filesize =
post_max_size =
```

in `/etc/php.ini`    (not in user’s `php.ini`)

Answer (score 1):

Check you `memory_limit`. Generally, `memory_limit` should be larger than `post_max_size`

Comment: yes its 8M now, can I set it to some large value say 1G, or is it have any relation to other internal things or other configurations?

Comment: getting the same log : `PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of 17481302 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: Setting it parameter to 1G is not a good idea, because one or few instanse may use all memory in the server.  Try to set 32M at first. As for me, better to use this solution http://www.plupload.com/ - it uplode file by chunks and you can use normal `upload_max_filesize`, `max_execution_time ` and `post_max_size `

Comment: Changed post_max_size and upload_max_size to 20M and memory_limit to 32M, and then tried to upload a 16mb file, issue is still there, server error log says the same `PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of 17470650 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: Can you in the beginnig `.php` file, which receive file, make: `exit( ini_get('upload_max_filesize').':'.ini_get('post_max_size').':'.ini_get('memory_limit') );` - I think something wrong with setting this params. And show me result

Comment: `20M:20M:` got this only `ini_get('memory_‌​limit') ` is empty :O

Comment: it's strange, because you set memory_limit to 32M. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315358/php-warning-post-content-length-of-113-bytes-exceeds-the-limit-of-1988100096-b) a good answer, maybe helps you

Comment: for test, try set `memory_limit` to `-1` (it means unlimited)

Comment: My server admin did something, now its ok, I asked him that what causes that issue, after his mail arrived I'll comment or post that here. thanks for your time @creatoR

Comment: And another one test: make `ini_set` in file (from previous comment) for all parameter: `ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '30M'); ini_set('post_max_size', '30M'); ini_set('memory_‌​limit', '30M');` and try to upload file with 16MB

Answer (score 0):

sorry i misunderstood the problem.here is my new answer.you are probably facing the problem because of the limited size of `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` in your php configuration file.i.e.php.ini

so please change `"post_max_size"`,`upload_max_filesize` from 8M to 32M in php.ini.your problem will be solved :) and then restart your server

Comment: nop, I dint load the file into db(only file name, i just tried to say that noting happens if my form contains a larger file), the problem is not with this..

Comment: u mean to say nothing happens when your filename is larger?

Comment: yep bro.. got this server error log `PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of 17481302 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: than change "post_max_size" from 8M to 32M in php.ini.your problem will be solved :) and then restart your server

Comment: Already changed that to 1G, but nothing happens...,or exactly put 32M?

Comment: Already did bro, after that I posted my question, but now I feels like may be issue with memory_limit, checkng..

Comment: @arun_php please change the limit of upload_max_filesize also.