# Apache or php is losing my post parameter

Tags: php, apache, post, vagrant

a very strange issue: I've set up a development server with vagrant. After debugging I found out, that the $_POST array of php is always empty.

So I reset everything and tried the following script on my local, vagrant set up, development server and my live server to ensure it works fine:

```
<?php
    var_dump($_POST);
    var_dump($_GET);
    var_dump($_REQUEST);
    phpinfo();
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="POST">
            <input type="submit" name="submitbutton" value="submitbuttonvalue" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

On my local machine the $_POST array is empty after submission, on the live server it isn't.

So I disabled shared folders and this fance stuff and tried all network interfaces of the VM but it didn't work. Here is my phpinfo output.

http://www.file-upload.net/download-9568691/phpinfo.pdf.html

Can I check where it is lost? The content length of the header varies, when I change the post parameters. I deleted any htaccess file, so there is no redirect.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Ou man,

I found the following in my apache log ... damn newbie

```
PHP Warning:  Unknown: POST Content-Length of 30 bytes exceeds the limit of 10 bytes in Unknown on line 0,
```

sorry :)

Comment: don't you think 10 bytes is bit too restrictive on post limit?

Comment: Yeah, the definition in php.ini was wrong. (10MB, not 10M) Sorry, I tried to accept my answer to close this question, but I am not allowed to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the error says that you have exceeded limit , there are probably too many post in your form. Adjust your php.ini settings or removed unsed post in the form.

I think this link will be helpful for you.

[PHP Warning: POST Content-Length of 8978294 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719495/php-warning-post-content-length-of-8978294-bytes-exceeds-the-limit-of-8388608-b)

[PHP Warning: POST Content-Length of 113 bytes exceeds the limit of -1988100096 bytes in Unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315358/php-warning-post-content-length-of-113-bytes-exceeds-the-limit-of-1988100096-b)