# Warning: POST Content-Length of 11394639 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes

Tags: php, json, php-ini

I have gone through all the solutions that I could find including [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719495/php-warning-post-content-length-of-8978294-bytes-exceeds-the-limit-of-8388608-b)
[ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315358/php-warning-post-content-length-of-113-bytes-exceeds-the-limit-of-1988100096-b) but couldn't resolve my problem.

I have made following changes to both php.ini production & development version;

```
post_max_size = 5000M
upload_max_filesize = 5000M
```

However it doesn't make any difference. If I am trying to upload image files of large value, I am receiving

below response error in my console-log;

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  POST Content-Length of 11394639 bytes exceeds the limit of 
8388608 bytes in <b>Unknown </b> on line <b>0</b><br /> []

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
```

I am hoping to have clarified my issue. Thanks for looking into it in advance !

Comment: Do this - do `phpinfo();` on the page, and see where is `php.ini` located. Make sure you edit the right file, and restart the server?

Comment: I have php production and development version and I have changed both but still doesn't help...!!

Answer (score 1):

> I have made following changes to both php.ini production & development version;
>
> post_max_size = 5000M
> upload_max_filesize = 5000M

I did have the same issue, but after changing the php.ini file and rebooting apache this worked for me.

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

I can see that you have some issue there. Check the file against any dodgy characters as it seems to be causing an issue. Sometimes when you want to upload a file, its name could have illegal characters for the database or js. Make sure that every character in the file name you try to upload does not have any illegal character, or it is encoded/decoded accordingly.

I hope I helped - this is my first post.

Let me know how did it go!

Best wishes,
mateekk

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my ubuntu 16.04. 
After the upgrading of php, I have several php.ini and at the begining I was mixed up.

Under 
**/etc/php**, 
I have the folders **php5.5**, **php5.6**, **php7.0**, **php7.1**, so be sure to correct the right one (because ,due to legacy, I was used to work in **/etc/php5**).