# Handling Very Large Uploads

Tags: php, http, upload, ftp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Very large uploads with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864570/very-large-uploads-with-php)

First question here !
I have seen some similar topics but never with the exact same issue I'm having.

I am currently managing a college campus server whose goal is to allow students to upload and download all sorts of files. Currently, if a file is larger than 1.5GB or so, the upload will fail. This may be because we are currently using the http protocol and at first, I was all for switching to ftp but I've recently learned that it is much more browser related (most won't allow uploads larger than 4GB...).

The only imperative is to allow uploads on the browser, without using an external application. Is using an applet the only choice ? Can Java or Silverlight applets be avoided (if possible, I would like to prevent users from getting the "You need to install X to Y" or "Will you allow X to use Y" messages). Maybe flash? Or you can be even more reassuring by telling me that it is possible with standard http or ftp ? I'm talking very large files (10GB would be a nice upper limit).

I have of course removed any php related limitation.

Thanks a lot for any info or remark ;)

Comment: The only way I can suggest you is that you should create a client and handle the file sharing with socket. 10 Gigabyte is a huge size and cannot be handled by HTTP protocol. If you can use socket programming, tell me to help you to keep on this way...

Comment: @Dale : Looking into it, thanks! I hadn't noticed this one.

Comment: @Soroush Khosravi : I don't know much about socket programming but if that implies that users must use a different client, I'm afraid it is a no go. But again, maybe I didn't quite understand what you said. My only imperative is that users must be able to upload/download on any operating system, any modern web browser without having to use an external application.

Comment: It is not possible that you create a web client for all type of browsers. You should create a client for each OS. The best way I can suggest you , is to create a client with java. Java runs easily on all of Operating Systems (windows, mac, Linux). Again, It is NOT POSSIBLE to handle this size with php. Just think a moment that at progress of 90 %, the upload fails ! Is it good ? If you handle it by TCP protocol, You can resume failed uploads...

Comment: Java seems to be the way to go then because I don't want users to have to download a client just to be able to use our services right?

Comment: To be honest, your original desire to go with FTP is probably right on target.  Given the nature of the problem being solved, there is no shame in asking people to have an FTP client to upload a multi-gigabyte file.