# Can't Upload big files with PHP (tried all other answers)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have changed the php.ini file and added a set_time_limit(0) on the top of my page and i still cant upload big files with php. I am also using ajax and javascript to upload, and i can upload 400Mb files. i was trying to upload a 3.2GB file on WAMP.

My code:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
session_start();
include('../Connect/Connect.php');

$User = $_SESSION['User'];
$Files = $_FILES['File'];
if(isset($User))
{
    if(!empty($Files))
    {
        for($X = 0; $X < count($Files['name']); $X++)
        {
            $Name = $Files['name'][$X];
            $TMP = $Files['tmp_name'][$X];

            move_uploaded_file($TMP, '../Users/' . $User . '/' . $Name);
        }
    }
}
else
{
    header("location:../"); 
}
header("location:index.php");
$Connect->close();
?>
```

[image: Memory Limit]

[image: Upload Limit]

Comment: so you're saying you can upload 3.2 GB in less than 5 minutes? If yes, then I do wish I had your internet connection...

Comment: This question should help explain the issue you might be having.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864570/very-large-uploads-with-php

Comment: Sorry, I really shouldn't be that ironic. Please check max_input_time ...

Comment: So.... what happens when you do try and upload a large file other than "it doesn't work"?

Comment: check your apache error log.

Answer (score 1):

- check your browser, that it supports >2 GB files
- set POST_MAX_SIZE higher than UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE (ofcourse set
  normal values in settings, not like memory_limit 10 000GB....
- max_input_time set for example to 30000
- check x64 or x86 OS/Browser
- had on debian with php 5.3.21 error, that it does not allow >2GB files cause of bug in PHP -> it just gives u a chance that u may get
  php version with wrong atoi() and atol() converting.

Comment: i did all of that i think i stated my problem wrong, the total amount of files is 104 the equals 3.2GB i am just testing the bandwidth of my server and how much it can handle, maybe theres a problem with php uploading 104 files...

Comment: Look under UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE, there is: MAX_FILE_UPLOADS => set it to 200 and then try your 104 files. For the future: these problems you must test step by step, Can upload 1 file? try 104 files, 104 files dont work? Try 50 files and so on.... and try and try and then u will get what may be the problem. Analyze if it always buggs after X time, or after X mbytes uploaded.. Anyway as someone wrote here: check your apache error log ;)