# How to upload big file

Tags: php, html

I am not pretty familiar with php. I do not want to sound silly but I really want to know how to upload a local big file in a web page without php involved? Is there any apache module offer this feature?

Thanks in advance.

PS: note the difference between big file and small file uploading, that big file uploading might need more data buffer in the receiving end, as far as I know.

Comment: change "upload_max_filesize"  variable in php.ini configuration file according to your requirement

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Very large uploads with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864570/very-large-uploads-with-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.htaccess`

```
php_flag file_uploads On
php_value memory_limit 800M
php_value post_max_size 800M
php_value upload_max_filesize 2000M
```

change the values according to your need, Place your .htacces in root of your appliation

A `.htaccess` file is a method to configure the details of your website without modifying server config file.

**Creating .htaccess file.**

.htaccess file can be created using  a Text editor make sure to name it **.htaccess** with no other extension ending.

The configurations inside the .htaccess file will affect the whole files and sub-directory inside a directory.

Comment: What is this ".htaccess" for?

Comment: `.htaccess` is a configuration file for use on web servers running the Apache Web Server software. Read more about .htaccess http://www.htaccess-guide.com/

Comment: but how does this modified configuration help upload a file? cause I even do not how to implement the basic feature that upload a file.

Comment: @lulyon than you have should learn things first

Answer (score -1):

Just for the record, I've found a pretty convenient demo based on jquery, which is comfortable to use and solved my problem. [jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)